# Video Lag when streaming HD Video to XBox360 via PS3 Media Server

Tags: xbox360, streaming, hdvideo

I've been using [PS3 Media Server](http://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/) to stream video to my XBox 360 for a while now, because I don't like the whole Windows Media Center Extender thing (I also think I tried it at one point and it won't stream this type of media). Some of it is HD, some SD.

Just recently, HD video (example: 720p, mkv, ripped from BluRay) has started to lag behind its audio. For longer videos - like an hour long TV show, or a 2 hour movie - by the end, it's extremely noticeable and annoying.

I know it's not the video file itself that's out of sync because if I watch in on the computer it doesn't lag at all. I'm pretty sure I'm using the latest version of PS3MS, too.

Does anyone have any suggestions for ways to fix this or alternative solutions?

Comment: Curious why this was closed. Can anyone comment on that?

Answer (score 0):

pause the video momentarily, with 360 you cant see it but in ps3 there a menu that shows how many mbps the video and audio are doin, they drop sometimes depending on what else you may be doin, if you pause it momentarily or even pause then rewind 1 sec, when you restart the movie should be sync again or studder a sec and then be sync

Comment: While this might be working, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem for me.